# How can I sort a table column by clicking on thead using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

I have this part of code on my PHP file which drains data from my database and creates a table with my all registers

```
<table class="scroll" id="cpersons">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row[0];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[1];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[2];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[3];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[4];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[5];?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endwhile;?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried many different ways of doing this with jQuery but nothing worked for me.

How can I sort my table by clicking on any `<thead>` element (id, First name, ...) with ascending and descending order of the current column using jQuery?

**I thought** a code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#cpersons thead tr th").click(function () {
        ownerIndex = $(this).index() + 1;
        $("#cpersons tbody tr td:nth-child("+ownerIndex+")").whatHereToSortMyTable(?);
    });
});
```

What can I replace `whatHereToSortMyTable(?)` with in this code to correctly sort as I described?

Comment: I find datatable plugin very useful for rendering table. https://datatables.net/

Comment: There is no simple function you can call which would do this.  You'd either use a plugin for rendering the table which has this functionality included or you'd write your own functionality, which would be a lot more involved than just a single function call.